# Connecting the tables in a database

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys

I have created a simple database in SQL Server Express which consists of three tables: `Inventory`, `Customers`, `Orders`.

I try to connect them in db diagram forcing the primary keys of `Inventory` and `Customers` (`CarID` and `CustID`) as foreign keys to `Orders`. However, when I try to save the diagram, I receive an error that does not allow me to save the diagram and link the tables.

The error indicates:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Orders_Inventory". The conflict occurred in database "AutoLot",
>   table "dbo.Inventory", column 'CarID'.

`FK_Orders_Inventory` is the connection between `Inventory` and `Orders`. What could be a potential cause of the error?

Comment: It probably means that the foreign key cannot be created because the foreign key is currently being violated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data currently in the table is probably not conforming to the constraints you have defined.

Make sure the data is consistent with the constraints before adding them.

In this case, one of the foreign keys you are defining fails because the column you are defining it on (in the `Inventory` table) contains values that do not exist on the referenced column (`CarId`) in the foreign table.

Answer (score 1):

You have a CarID value in the child table that does not exist in the parent table.